# Why is PHAssetCollection Count 0?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios8, xcode6

I'm trying to wrangle the new photo features of iOS 8's photo editing capabilities. Their documentation is very sparse so I'd love some input from you as to what might be going on.

I am trying to fetch ALL the images the user has saved. I am doing a fetch but it keeps telling me the result size is 0. It also shoots out a weird error along with it

```
func initController()
    {
        _userAlbums = PHCollectionList.fetchTopLevelUserCollectionsWithOptions(nil)//GET PERMISSION BEFORE DOING THIS
        println("Albums count is \(_userAlbums.count)") //error when printing this
    }
```

This prints out

> ```
> 2014-10-27 17:43:50.254 appiOS[4854:732084] [PLLogging] ***** Error: logging directory does not exist
> ```
>
> /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/DiagnosticLogs/
>
> ```
> Albums count is 0
> ```

There are at least 100 images on the iPad I am using. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Update:

Using

```
_userAlbums = PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithOptions(nil)
```

Works

Comment: `fetchTopLevelUserCollectionsWithOptions` is not a PHCollectionList method. It is a PHCollection method. So you are already talking to the wrong class.

Comment: Also it looks like your app is crashing for some other reason. If I were you, I'd start by looking into why _that_ is before going any further.

Comment: It doesn't actually crash, it just shows that log whenever I try to print an PHCollection object

Comment: But you have to ask yourself why that is. When I run your code on my machine, I don't get that message. So really, I think you should stop and worry about that. Perhaps Xcode is not properly installed.

Comment: I downloaded a sample project and it too shows that log error when I print out that object. So ya maybe I do need a reinstall

Comment: I'm sorry I can't be any more helpful about what's wrong, but I do think you should try to do something about it. That message is not normal. I'm a bit worried that the problem is at the level of your _system_ installation.

Comment: My thanks I will look into it! I am going to load this on a colleagues computer and see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> There are at least 100 images on the iPad I am using. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

You are not doing anything wrong. Your expectations seem a bit out of whack, though. The statement "there are at least 100 images" seems indicative of a deeper misconception, because, after all, `PHCollectionList.fetchTopLevelUserCollectionsWithOptions` has *nothing to do with images*. It has to do with, uh, top level user collections. Evidently your device doesn't have any of those.

But now go to the Photos app on your iPad and make a few albums. *Those* are top level user collections! So then run your app again. Assuming you've been granted permission to access the photo library, now your logging will result in a number larger than 0.